# Происхождение слова "кудесник"

Tags: этимология

Все помнят бессмертные строчки А.С. Пушкина из "Песни о вещем Олеге":

«Скажи мне, кудесник, любимец богов,
      Что сбудется в жизни со мною?
И скоро ль, на радость соседей-врагов,
      Могильной засыплюсь землею?
Открой мне всю правду, не бойся меня:
В награду любого возьмешь ты коня».

Меня интересует слово "кудесник". Понятно, что это синоним словам "волшебник", "маг", "чародей", но интересно происхождение слова.

Comment: Интересна формула:- любимец богов. Именно так переводится Зардуст- (любимец Бога) (С)Питама- батюшка. Ку- дело, умение, дес(з)-десница. Возможно, " творящий мановением руки". Чародей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Древнерусский глагол "чути" (чувствовать) имел в языке какой-то особенный оттенок, похожий на сверхчувствительность.

Например: чуткий - тонко чувствующий, чуть - еле заметно, чуять - распознавать, интуитивно чувствовать, чудо - сначала просто "чувствуемое, наблюдаемое" и только в современном языке - удивительное и необыкновенное.

Вот и кудесник (исконное слово)- это суффиксальное производное от кудо/кудеса (чудеса), чередование К/Ч в корне, о.-с. основа cudo.

Comment: Интересно. А "чудь" (которая белоглазая) и "чудной" того же корня?

Comment: Чудь- от "чу"- древнейшее из, известных мне, названий -вода, река.
Интересна этимология названия реки Чусувая: чу- вода, находим в древнем названии рек, описанных в Авесте, су- вода на тюрском, ва- вода на коми( угорская группа языков). Потому чудь-, чуваш (чоаш),  влгар, рось- речники, живущие у воды или на воде, на разных языках в разное время. Чудной, возможно, того же корня в значении -необычный-.